# "Type to search" with a vb.net winform listbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In many apps, you can quickly find an item in a list by typing the first few characters.

For example, let's say I have a databound list with six names in it: Aaron, Allison, Abdul, Bob, Orville and Peter". If I type "Ab" on my keyboard, I expect the list to jump to "Abdul". If I type "Aaa", I expect it to jump to Allison ("a" for Aaron, "a" again for the second letter in Aaron, then the final "a" to skip to Allison)

I can't seem to do this in vb.net though. When I type "Ab" in a ListBox, the selected item jumps from Aaron, then to Bob, and typing "Aa" jumps from Aaron straight to Allison)

WPF has the `TextSearch.TextPath` property which lets you "type to search" using a column on a datatable (e.g. "FirstName"), but I can't seem to find an equivalent in WinForms. I know I can add a RowFilter and a textbox, and / or I could use a variable, a timer and some code to keep track of what was pressed then clear the variable if nothing has been typed for a few seconds, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

So, is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, there is nothing built into WinForms to do this.

Comment: Hello! Where is the code behind this story? Do you mean _Match Whole Word_ search? _Start with_ and/or _contain_ search? And what is the type of the `.DataSource`? `List<T>`, `BindingSource`, `DataTable` ? Relevant code and details please.

Comment: @dr.null, it seems to me that the point of the question is to determine whether it can be done without code first, before trying to do it manually.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I see but still, the problem remains Johni. The 3rd paragraph indicates that the OP has a search routine that does not return the desired result. That's why I asked for some details. If it's all about Yes/No, then you have answered that already.

Comment: @dr.null there's no search routine yet, what I mentioned in paragraph 3 is what happens in a default ListBox (if you add a listbox and hardcode some items into it, you can type the first letter to skip to that letter. It's not a search, just a "skip to that letter" which is not ideal when you've got 150+ items that all start with "M" and you want to get to "Mona" quickly)

Comment: _there's no search routine yet..._. then you need to write one like the provided answer. You can add more key methods to for example, clear/edit the `keystrokes` list when you press `Delete` / `Back` keys. Handle the `Enter` key to select the next match - if any - starting the search from the current `SelectedIndex` + 1. Ctrl+Enter to search backward....etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built in way that I (or commenters at the present) know of.

This is how I may do it

```vb
Private names As List(Of String)
Private keystrokes As New List(Of Char)()
Private processTimer As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf processAction, Nothing, -1, -1)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    names = {"Aaron", "Allison", "Abdul", "Bob", "Orville"}.OrderBy(Function(s) s).ToList()
    ListBox1.DataSource = names
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = True
    keystrokes.Add(e.KeyChar)
    processTimer.Change(250, -1)
End Sub

Private Sub processAction(state As Object)
    Dim searchString = New String(keystrokes.ToArray()).ToUpper()
    keystrokes.Clear()
    Dim match = names.FirstOrDefault(Function(name) name.ToUpper().StartsWith(searchString))
    If match = "" Then
        SelectListboxIndex(names.Concat({searchString}).OrderBy(Function(name) name).ToList().FindIndex(Function(name) name.ToUpper() = searchString.ToUpper()))
    Else
        SelectListboxIndex(names.FindIndex(Function(name) name.ToUpper() = match.ToUpper()))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SelectListboxIndex(index As Integer)
    If ListBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        ListBox1.Invoke(New Action(Of Integer)(AddressOf SelectListboxIndex), index)
    Else
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Math.Max(Math.Min(index, ListBox1.Items.Count - 1), 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Not sure why you want `aaa` to select Allison, but the logic can be modified.

Comment: I did a few quick tests, and looks like I was wrong about the Aaron thing. I thought you could press "aa" twice to select Aaron, then upon the third press, due to the list not having an item starting with "aaa" the cursor would just move to the next "A" in the list, which would be Allison. But as it turns out, when you press "aa", it goes to Aaron first, then immediately to Allison, no third "a" press required. But typing "bo" would select Bob as expected. I tried this with a JSFiddle, and by creating folders in Windows Explorer.